# Local script debugging for python in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to follow the instructions mentioned on the [vscode page for debugging a local python script](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_local-script-debugging). According to the instructions, I have added the piece of code to my script. Next, I opened the integrated terminal and ran my script. I get the message `waiting for debugger to attach`.

Now I try to follow the step 6 of the instructions:

> Switch to the Run view, select the appropriate configuration from the debugger dropdown list, and start the debugger.

So, I click on the run and debug button (one on the bottom left in the picture) and then click `Python: Attach using process id` (top of the picture).

[image]

However, the debugger does not get attached.

I am not sure where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the content of the file "[launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_initialize-configurations)" you use for configuration debugging:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console":"integratedTerminal",
            
        }
    ]
}
```

then click *F5*: The code stays at "`debugpy.breakpoint()`" as described in the documentation.

[image]